# Grapesjs with plugin Ckeditor show over my text

Tags: ckeditor, grapesjs, mjml

This is my code for Grapesjs editor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/css/grapes.min.css">

    <script src="libs/grapes.min.js"></script>

    <script src="libs/mjml/index.js"></script>

    <script src="libs/grapesjs-plugin-ckeditor.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="gjs">
    <mjml>
        <mj-body>
            <!-- Your MJML body here -->
            <mj-section>
                <mj-column>
                    <mj-text>My Company</mj-text>
                </mj-column>
            </mj-section>
        </mj-body>
    </mjml>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = grapesjs.init({
        fromElement: true,
        container: '#gjs',
        style: '.txt-red{color: red}',
        plugins: ['grapesjs-mjml', 'gjs-plugin-ckeditor'],
        pluginsOpts: {
            'grapesjs-mjml': {},
            'gjs-plugin-ckeditor': {}
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and problem is that Ckeditor show toolbar over my text and its impossible to edit text. Its happen when text box is too small.

[image]

Is it possible to set some settings or how to fix it?